# check if inner functions were created by the same function

Tags: python, python-3.x

lets supose that i have something like:

```
def a(b):
   def c(d):
      # do someting 
      # ...
      # ...
      return something_else
   return c
```

and then this:

```
q = a(54)
w = a(97)
e = a(12)
```

is there any way to know if for example q and w where both created by a ? or is there anything that i can make to check it ?

i though about doing an empty class and then inheit from that one overwriting __call__ and using issubclass but it seems a little bit hacky (and will raise if its actually a normal function), and maybe there is a better option.

thanks.

Comment: You could probably do something hackish with closures.

Answer (score 1):

You could duck punch it:

```py
def a(b):
   def c(d):
     # do stuff
     return stuff
   c.created_by = 'a'
   return c
```

So then when you use it...

```
q = a(54)
w = a(97)

q.created_by == w.created_by # True
```

Not judging since I don't know why you're trying to do this, or really understand the problem, but personally I think this is a bigger hack than doing it via classes:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b

class C(A):
    def do_stuff(self, d):
        return self.b * d

q = C(54)
w = C(97)

isinstance(q, A) # True
```